# Screened potential of charged impurity in a 2-dimentional electron gas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, scattering

What's the analytical relation of screened potential of charged impurity in a 2-dimentional electron gas?

Comment: In real space or in momentum space?

Comment: In real space. In fact, I could calculate it in momentum space but it's likely impossible to inverse Fourier transform of it. The obtained relation is complicated. But, I need an analytical relation for it in real space.